# "Verja" vs "cancela"

Tags: traducción, dialectos

Dictionary says both mean "gate". I want to know if there is any finer difference between the two, especially regional ones. What's the word you use for gate in your regions? More specifically I would like to know what the Mexicans use.

Comment: In Spain `Verja` is more used, I've never hear `Cancela` in a conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Verja or Cancela use to refer to metallic structures made of tubes. have you googled images to see the difference? a verja is a metallic structure made of tubes that keep people outside a zone, it is also used as gate in some zones.

A cancela is a door/gate usually side to side with a verja, cancela is more used to refer to a metallic gate but can also be used as verja, it will depend on who are you talking to and who is he/she from.

I think i'm right but i am no linguist

Comment: I did google the images before asking the question and it threw similar images for both the words. So, you're saying verja is more like a boundary/barricade made of metal tubes/rods while a cancela is a metal gate? But then you say that it depends on the person I am speaking to. So what do these words mean in your region? Which word would people use to refer to a gate (metal or otherwise) in your country/region?

Comment: I've never hear `cancela` as gate. I'm from Cuba, lived in mexico, colombia and miami.

Comment: This answer is correct. According to RAE Verja is *Enrejado que sirve de puerta, ventana o, especialmente, cerca.*, and *cancela* is when it is used as a door for an entrance as a garden, patio. *Verja pequeña que se pone en el umbral de algunas casas para reservar el portal o zaguán del libre acceso del público*. *Cancela* is more used in *Andalucia*. *En Andalucía, verja, comúnmente de hierro y muy labrada*. Nowadays is more common to say *abre la verja* rather than *abre la cancela*.